# Как сделать бессмертный сервис?

Tags: java, android

Есть задача создать файл и проверять есть ли изменения в этом файле.Как это . правильно реализовать ?Можно ли как то сделать BroadcastReciver который будет уведомлять мое приложение об изменении в файле  когда прилодение еще не запущено